# How to improve runtime on csv function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a running cod that runs but it takes a LONG time to run. By viewing my code, is there any way to improve the speed? I am thinking to loop the query and then put it all in a dictionary and then writer it to a CSV file, but i am having issues. Here is my code:

```
#Import the appropriate models and functions needed for our script
from cbapi.response import *
import logging 
import csv 

#Connect to our CB Server
conn = CbResponseAPI() 

#Sample Query
q = "ipAddress:192.0.0.5"

#Initial our query
process_query = conn.select(Process).where(q).group_by("id")

#Set your path 
my_path='/Users/path/123.csv'
    
#all object properties for event 
objects=['childproc_count',
   'cmdline',
   'comms_ip',
   'crossproc_count',
   'filemod_count',
   'filtering_known_dlls',
   'group',
   'host_type',
   'hostname',
   'id',
   'interface_ip',
   'last_server_update',
   'last_update',
   'modload_count',
   'netconn_count',
   'os_type',
   'parent_id',
   'parent_md5',
   'parent_name',
   'parent_pid',
   'parent_unique_id',
   'path',
   'process_md5',
   'process_name',
   'process_pid',
   'process_sha256',
   'processblock_count',
   'regmod_count',
   'segment_id',
   'sensor_id',
   'start',
   'terminated',
   'unique_id',
   'username']

with open(my_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
    header=objects #add columns
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    
    for x in process_query:
        
        dd={'id': x.id, 
            'childproc_count':x.childproc_count, 
            'cmdline':x.cmdline, 
            'comms_ip':x.comms_ip 
            'filemod_count':x.filemod_count, 
            'filtering_known_dlls':x.filtering_known_dlls,
            'group':x.group, 
            'host_type':x.host_type ,
            'hostname':x.hostname,
            'interface_ip':x.interface_ip, 
            'last_server_update':x.last_server_update,
            'last_update':x.last_update, 
            'modload_count':x.modload_count,
            'netconn_count':x.netconn_count, 
            'os_type':x.os_type,
            'parent_id':x.parent_id, 
            'parent_md5':x.parnet_md5,
            'parent_name':x.parent_name, 
            'parent_pid':x.parent_pid,
            'parent_unique_id':x.parent_unique_id, 
            'path':x.path,
            'process_md5':x.process_md5, 
            'process_name':x.process_name,
            'process_pid':x.process_pid, 
            'process_sha256':x.process_sha256,
            'processblock_count':x.processblock_count, 
            'regmod_count':x.regmod_count,
            'segment_id':x.segment_id, 
            'sensor_id':x.sensor_id,
            'start':x.start, 
            'terminated':x.terminated,
            'unique_id':x.unique_id, 
            'username':x.username }
            }
        
    
    writer.writerow(dd)
```

The results for the query object is 465,000 records and takes about 30 minutes + to run this script completely which is not the most efficient.

Comment: Looking at the code it should be fast. The question is, what this `process_query = conn.select(Process).where(q).group_by("id")` is doing. For every iteration of `for x in process_query:` it queries the server?

Comment: @AndrejKesely. I was about to suggets running a profiler for the same reason. It doesn't make sense unless you can support the claim that CSV is messing up with actual timing data.

Comment: The code seems not that inefficient. Maybe use timeit to see where the time is spent (and set number of repetions very low, perhaps even number=1, since it is so slow)